# Endeca cluster load balancing

Tags: apache, nginx, load-balancing, endeca, f5

I have an Endeca cluster setup with 3 dgraph(1 EAC Central Server and 2 EAC agent only instances). I am trying to put an Apache mod_proxy load balancer for testing purpose before the MDEX engines(I am using presentation API to hit the MDEX engine(we are working on assembler API also)). We shall be having an F5(or Nginx, which one shall be better?) hardware load balancer when we'll shall do the actual deployment. My apache server is listening at port 5555, All my Dgraphs are running at port 15000 on three different host. I'm directing the all my queries to apache load balancer.

```
MDEX_HOST = localhost
MDEX_PORT = 5555
private static ENEConnection createConnection() {...}
```

And here is my Apache Load balancer configuration. Load balancer modules included in httpd.conf file `mod_proxy, mod_proxy_balancer, mod_proxy_connect, mod_proxy_http, mod_negotiation.` I have put the load balancer configuration in httpd-vhosts.conf file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:5555 
<VirtualHost *:5555>
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/"
env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
ServerName localhost
ProxyPass / balancer://cluster/
<Proxy balancer://cluster>
BalancerMember http://172.16.26.129:15000 loadfactor=1 retry=0 route=1
BalancerMember http://172.16.26.210:15000 loadfactor=1 retry=0 route=2
BalancerMember http://172.16.27.87:15000 loadfactor=1 retry=0 route=3
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from none
Allow from all
ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
<Location /balancer-manager>
SetHandler balancer
</Location>
```

When I do a query(Type ahead service) I'm getting the following error..

```
** Error Fri Apr 10 20:05:53 IST 2015 1428676553858 /atg/rest/processor/RestActorManager Caused by (#6):com.endeca.navigation.ENEException: HTTP Error 404 - Navigation Engine not able to process request 'http://localhost:5555/search?terms=je&rank=0&offset=0&irversion=640'.
```

Can anyone please see my load balancer configuration what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You said your dgraphs are running in port# 1500, load-balancing config shows it as 15000, whereas your error shows that you are attempting to hit 5555.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I made a typo in posting the question. My DGRPAHs are running at port number 15000 and apache is listening at port 5555 only, and I have set the MDEX host to load balancer port (5555)(I tried changing the ports and I included the previous log error msg. in the question, sorry! ). The load balancer is supposed to re-write the URL but that is not happening.
I have edited the question. Please Help.

Comment: I was creating a new vhost.conf(in the conf folder), I had to edit and replace the old one in the extras folder. It is now working flawlessly.